# How to share session cookie with Identity Server ASP.NET app and OWIN?

Tags: cookies, owin, thinktecture-ident-server, machinekey

I am using Identity Server v2 along with SessionAuthenticationModule.

I would like to add a new OWIN app (hosted in IIS) which can share the same session cookie "*idsrvauth*" with my existing STS.

How do I do this please?

1. Can the SessionAuthenticationModule decrypt the session cookie and set the IPrincipal in the OWIN app?
2. Or should I use OWIN middleware to do this? Is there existing middleware or will I need to write new?

I have the same **machineKey** in each web.config but when accessing the OWIN site, I get a CryptographicException:

```
CryptographicException: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.
 System.Web.Security.Cryptography.HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper.HomogenizeErrors(Func`2 func, Byte[] input) +246
 System.IdentityModel.Services.MachineKeyTransform.Decode(Byte[] encoded) +200
 System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ApplyTransforms(Byte[] cookie, Boolean outbound) +173
 System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(XmlReader reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +752
 System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(Byte[] token, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +99
 System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.ReadSessionTokenFromCookie(Byte[] sessionCookie) +1233
 System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(SessionSecurityToken& sessionToken) +314
 System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +243
 System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

Comment: Instead of this, I decided to share a separate cookie between the 2 apps and have the first app responsible for creating the session data.

In the web.config of the second (OWIN) app, I remove the SessionAuthenticationModule.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and in my case it was missing `validation="SHA1"` in `<machineKey ... >` element.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.85).aspx) it is a default one, but only after adding that explicitly my machine-key-based cryptography started working across 2 sites.